# How to tell if a 4WD vehicle features LSD and/or ADD?

Tags: gears, 4wd, differential, rear-differential, front-differential

I am about to change oil in the front and rear differentials or my Toyota Hilux (KUN26R) which is a part-time 4WD vehicle. Regarding what gear oil to use and how much, the manual says:

> Oil type:
>
> With limited-slip  differential Hypoid gear oil LSD AP GL-5
>
> Without limited-slip  differential Hypoid gear oil AP GL-5
>
> Front:
>
> With A.D.D. 1.7L
>
> Without A.D.D. 1.5L
>
> Rear: 3.4L

How do I tell if either front or rear diffs have LSD? How do I tell if front diff has ADD?

Comment: Use the level indicator - usually built into the dif...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack up the front end and spin one tire by hand.  If the other tire spins in the same direction, you have an LSD.

Examine the area next to the front differential.  If you have a square housing and actuator (it will have a vacuum line attached to it) like the pictures below, you have the Toyota ADD system.  (Granted this shows the system disassembled.)

[image]

[image]